# C++ Object Filter Engine similar to sql syntax

Tags: c++

Is there a c++ library which provides SQL like syntax to filter/query for specific objects based upon their Getters/Properties ? Im looking for something similar to this http://www.thomasfrank.se/sqlike.html (thats for JS/AS) but written in C++. Requirements would be crossplattform, lightweight and (not a must but) hopefully not using boost.

E.g. i have implemented a scripting engine for my c++ code - my scripts can add callbacks to my C++ Objects. Now instead of writing a script for each object (actor) i wanted to apply it for all objects based upon a filter.

So in my script i would have something like

```
manager:AddListener("select name="SomeName" and age > 10 or weight < 10",SomeEvent,MyScriptFunc)
```

When a new Object is created, i would look through all listeners - if this objects property matches the configured one, i add it (e.g. object has property name=somename and age is above 10)

Currently i just identify my objects by a unique identifier (ID) - but i want to be more flexible when i apply the same event listeners to similar objects.

So basically, it would already be enough if there is a libary who creates a filter object from some string query.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/):

> SQLite is a software library that implements a self-contained, serverless, zero-configuration, transactional SQL database engine. SQLite is the most widely deployed SQL database engine in the world. The source code for SQLite is in the public domain.

You can create an in memory database to hold the C++ object attributes that you wish to query on:

```
sqlite3_open(":memory:", &db);
```

Then you can use the [One-Step Query Execution Interface](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/exec.html) to actually perform the queries.

To populate the database, you could use an IDL to describe your objects, and your IDL parser would create the C++ interface header files and the code to populate the database.

Comment: That is something completely different - SQLite is just like mysql or postgres - it just writes into a file and stores normal table data etc - im looking only for a query engine - not a database storage!

Comment: no - it needs a database connection - trust me, sqlite is nothing close to what im looking for - i have worked with sqlite before

Comment: @Steve: I am not denying SQLite needs a database, but it supports a relatively lightweight in-memory database that you can use to register your object information with so you can query over it. I thought that was what you were asking for. If you are looking for an SQL interface over some intrinsic type information in C++, I am not aware of any such thing. Regards

Comment: thanks, but i think that would be overkill tho! i probably have to write my own syntax/filter parser then